# JavaScript code assist in Eclipse project only works in certain cases

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-assist

I am using Eclipse Juno developing a static web project. My project uses several different JavaScript files. One of the files contains a function:

```
function IconData(size, url) {
    this.size = size;
    this.url = url;
}
```

I have another function that returns an object of type IconData:

```
function PageInfo() {
    this.iconData = function() {
        var iconData = new IconData();
        iconData.size = 10;
        iconData.url = "http://somepage.com/image.png";
        return iconData;
    }
}
```

In another JavaScript file I create an instance of PageInfo and call the function iconData:

```
var page = new PageInfo();
// populate stuff
var icon = page.iconData();
```

If I type icon. then CTRL+SPACE to start code assist I get the following message popups in Eclipse:

No Default Proposals

[image: No Default Proposals]

No Template Proposals

[image: No Template Proposals]

However, if I create a new instance of icon data such as:

```
var iconData = new IconData();
```

then I type iconData. then CTRL-SPACE the code assist pops up and show me all the possibilities:

[image: Code Assist Working]

Why doesn't code assist work in the first scenario but it works in the second?

P.S. I have Googled how to enable code assist for JavaScript in Eclipse I found several sites that said I need to make sure I have JavaScript Development Tools installed and I made sure that I have them installed so I know that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a limitation with JSDT. I suggest you that you install [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which extends JSDT to improve JS completion, hyperlink, hover.

Copy your JS files in a folder, convert your project as tern and  configure **Script path** with your folder. Please read [Getting Started](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started) to know how to do that.

Here a screenshot with your case (here *scripts* folder is configured as script path):

[image: Completion with tern.java]

Please note that tern.java is developed with Eclipse Luna, so I suggest you to use this version and not Juno.